# Is there a name to categorize instruments according to wether they can produce an infinity of F0 or not?

Tags: terminology, instruments

I'd like to know if there is a word, in English or any other language, that describe the category gathering the instruments able to play every frequency (tone, quarter tone, any arbitrary subdivision of a tone), as opposed to those that can't.

For instance, the violin can play any frequency (and basically an infinite amount) between A4 and A5, so can fretless instruments. An accordion or a guitar can't (at least not easily).